# How to start Service-only Android app

Tags: android, service

I am creating an application whose only component is a `service` which keeps on running in background (basically a proxy server) but I am not able to find a way how to start that service. Application can not have any UI or user interaction so I am not using Activity.
`Broadcast receiver` can listen to BOOT broadcast but how do I start service first time when it is installed and how can I keep it running? 
or is there a broadcast which I can listen after app is installed e.g. may be TIME_TICK but that has to be registered from activity I think.

Comment: I haven't tried this myself but would it be possible to start a service from the Application object?

Comment: I think it works http://android-codes-examples.blogspot.com/2011/11/running-service-in-background-on.html

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Unfortunately right now there is no reliable way to receive a broadcast event after your applicaiton has been installed, the [ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED) Intent does not broadcast to the newly installed package.

You will have to have a broadcast receiver class as well as your service in order to receive the [ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED) event.  I would also recommend adding the [ACTION_USER_PRESENT](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_USER_PRESENT) intent to be caught by that broadcast receiver, this requires Android 1.5 (minSDK=3), this will call your broadcast receiver whenever the user unlocks their phone.  The last thing that you can do to try to keep your service running without having it easily be shut down automatically is to call [Service.setForeground()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#setForeground(boolean)) in your service onCreate to tell Android that your service shouldn't be stopped, this was added mainly for mp3 player type services that have to keep running but can be used by any service.

Make sure you add the proper permissions for the boot_complete and user_present events in you manifest.

Here is a simple class that you can use as a broadcast receiver for the events.

```
package com.snctln.util.WeatherStatus;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

public class WeatherStatusServiceReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        if(intent.getAction() != null)
        {
            if(intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED) ||
                intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_USER_PRESENT))
            {
                context.startService(new Intent(context, WeatherStatusService.class));
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Good luck.

Comment: Good advice. One thing about Service.setForeground(): it no longer works in Android 2.0+. All "long-lived" services are now required to have a persistent notification in the notification area while they're running. Example here: http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/ForegroundService.html

Comment: ACTION_USER_PRESENT is an awesome tip. I've been struggling with keeping my service alive for ages, and this just solved it.

Comment: Found out, that from 3.0 upwards one needs to start the application at least once to enable getting the intent for it - weird, but works for me. That means, that one has to create a little activity (i.e. with introductory stuff) which is started after installation. After that you will receive the intents properly.

Comment: is that documented anywhere ubuntudroid?

Comment: @ArchimedesTrajano I know this question is old but it was the first result on Google. There is some documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-3.1.html#launchcontrols) and a good explanation [here](http://commonsware.com/blog/2011/07/13/boot-completed-regression-confirmed.html).

Answer (score 16):

Return `START_STICKY` in `Service.onStartCommand`

Android will restart your service

Comment: START_STICKY is valid only for Android 2.0+

Comment: but service has to run at least once to get the continuity right?

Answer (score 1):

I'm researching on the same issue. Here's is what I've found:
http://kfb-android.blogspot.de/2009/04/registering-for-timetick-after-reboot.html

That simple little demo shows a solution by playing a little bit of ping-pong between a `BroadcatReceiver` and a `Service`. The Receiver is registered to start at boot time by registering in the Manifest to receive `ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED`. It just starts a service when receviving `ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED`. The `Service` in turn registeres the `BroadcastReceiver` then for the `ACTION_TIME_TICK`.

The app logic will be implemented in the `BroadcastReceiver`.