# Finding my service is running or not in Android?

Tags: android, service, android-service

I have a service to contact the server to do some data transfer from my app periodically. Its working fine.

But when i restarted(switch off and on) my phone that service can not be restarted. so my idea  is that to start that service again when the user open my app after restarting the phone. For that, i have to know about my service is running or not? how to do it?

Any other idea to handle this scenario also thankful.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need an implementation of [`BroadcastReceiver`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html), which is intended on `BOOT_COMPLETED` action. Like this:

```
public class OnStartReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {


  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
//     your starting service code here
  }

}
```

Also, you should add [`receiver`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/receiver-element.html) tag to your manifest file with `android:name` = your fully qualified name of OnStartReceiver and intent-filter tag nested with [`BOOT_COMPLETED`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED) as intent name, like this:

```
<receiver android:name=".onStartReceiver">
   <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>                    
   </intent-filter>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a `BroadcastReceiver` to listen for the `ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED` event. More details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/990217/android-app-with-service-only/990944#990944).

Answer (score 0):

Use `AlarmManager` for scheduled tasks like this, so your service does not need to be in memory all of the time. As Mr. Ribery indicates, use a `BroadcastReceiver` with `ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED` to re-schedule your tasks after a phone reboot.