# how to stop or finish activity from called service?

Tags: android, service, android-activity

In my app I am required to Stop the activity(MyAct.java) when a service(BackgroundService.java) is called, and further i wish to continue this service(BackgroundService.java).please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implement a [started service](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/services.html), call startService(Intent service) in your activity(for instance, a button pressed) then call finish() immediately in your activity.

Check out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/990217/android-app-with-service-only) to see how to create a long running background service, even without need a activity to start the service.