# How can I create a android service for listen a server?

Tags: android, service

is there any way to listen a Server action using a service?i want to check server message for life time and do actions based on server message,please post a sample code

Comment: Your question is way to vague, but here's an answer:

_is there any way to listen a Server action using a service?_ **Yes, there is.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you looking for is a long time running background service, check out [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/990217/android-app-with-service-only).

Answer (score 0):

Here i have example of using service, but it's doing some other thing. You can work it out..
http://maephv.blogspot.com/2011/08/android-notification-in-your.html

But remember, that when screen comes off, services freeze. I don't know yet how to fix it, but maybe "background process"  is word to google