# how to open activity on screen unlock in android?

Tags: android, android-widget

In the application,I am trying to a make activity show when user opens the  screen lock (screen unlock) and when activity finish user open screen lock activity run back.I am trying

> Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON

but it is not working properly. And I also used

> USER_PRESENT

but I am not able get expected answer

I tried to find on google but was unsuccessful ,so I am confused how to make this type please tell me fast.

Comment: you can register ACTION_SCREEN_ON  only using a registerReceiver():

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1588061/android-how-to-receive-broadcast-intents-action-screen-on-off 

so you can try to build service which starts on boot: http://www.androidcompetencycenter.com/2009/06/start-service-at-boot/ 

and try to registerReceiver there

Comment: but i am not any message like service created, service destroy .please tell me fast

Comment: "please tell me fast" it's an order? i provide all information you needed ... i just build such thing ... but it's so annoying that i'll not tell you how exaclly do this

Comment: "but i am not any message like service created, service destroy" becouse u need to boot ... try this on real device ... add registerReciver in onStart of this service ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version of Android are you targeting?

I have been able to get `USER_PRESENT` working fine on 2.x devices, by declaring it in the manifest.

On 3.x & 4.x I was unable to get it working at first. On these later versions you need to run the activity at least once before the system will allow you to register for the event. This is not needed in 2.x.

- [Intent.ACTION_USER_PRESENT not received on HoneyComb or ICS (Samsung) devices](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10335152/383414)
- [android app with service only](https://stackoverflow.com/a/990944/383414)

I have succeeded with this on 2.x, 3.x and 4.x devices and it works. A simple option for an activity to run, if your app is a background app, is a welcome screen with configuration options on it. This would not be out of place in a background app, and satisfies the conditions.