# Intent.ACTION_USER_PRESENT not received on HoneyComb or ICS (Samsung) devices

Tags: android, android-intent, android-3.0-honeycomb, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I have a `BackgroundReceiver` set up to receive the `android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT` in the manifest file as per:

```
    <receiver android:name="com.demo.MyBroadcastReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

My overridden `onReceive(Context, Intent)` method is very simple:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
{
    if (intent != null)
    {

        if (Intent.ACTION_USER_PRESENT.equals(intent.getAction())
        {
            // wrapper for Log.d(String, String)
            Dbug.log("MyBroadcastReceiver: [" + intent.getAction() + "]");

            // this calls a service
            serviceExample(context, intent);
        }
    }
}
```

---

- This tested perfectly on 2.1, 2.2 & 2.3 devices (HTC Desire, HTC WildFire, Motorola Razr).
- This does not seem to work on HoneyComb (Samsung Galaxy Tab 10.1) or ICS (Samsung Galaxy Nexus) devices.
- As per this bug ([USER_PRESENT never fires on honeycomb and ICS when keyguard is disabled](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=25300)), I set the keyguard on the failing devices. It did not help.

**Questions:**

1. Is there some trick to using these intent actions on Android 3.x & 4.x?
2. Perhaps this is a known Samsung issue?
3. Or perhaps there is some device setting I have neglected on these devices?

Comment: this question implies it can be done: [Bring task to front on android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8750854/bring-task-to-front-on-android-intent-action-user-present)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a comment by [ubuntudroid](https://stackoverflow.com/users/304266/ubuntudroid) on this answer ([android app with service only](https://stackoverflow.com/a/990944/383414)) that says you need to start your activity at least once before it will correctly receive the required intents.

Apparently introduced in Android 3.0.

I have not tested this theory yet, but it would explain what you are seeing.

Comment: I have ran into similar behavior that would be explained by this. I was automatically deploying an APK to a device and then interacting with it via broadcast receivers. (Android 5.1.1). The USER_PRESENT action was received intermittently.