# How to monitor one application using another application in android operating system

Tags: java, android, monitoring

I want to monitor(**I want to check whether one currently running application fetches my contacts details**) all installed application of android operating system using one application. Can any one help me to sort this out or is possible to create such application in android.

Answer (score 0):

You can look at [this](http://androidforums.com/application-development/132611-how-can-i-get-list-all-installed-apps.html) topic on androidforums  with similar question. Maybe it helps to begin. Or you can look at [this](http://www.androidsnippets.com/get-installed-applications-with-name-package-name-version-and-icon) helper function

Answer (score 0):

> I want to monitor all installed application of android operating system using one application.

What is your definition of monitor?

- To know when [packages are added refer to this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/990217/android-app-with-service-only)
- To know which applications [are running in the fg/bg use this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5528441/68805)
- To know what the CPU speed and other stats use `adb shell ps`. Yes, you can run adb commands from an apk
- The [`ActivityManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html) class is quite helpful

Comment: I want to check whether one currently running application fetches my contacts details.

Comment: As far as I know, you can't do that. You can only listen for changes to your contacts using a `ContentObserver`