# How to create an Android service that runs like a Windows service?

Tags: android, android-service

I want to create a service that will have no user interface and always run in the background - looking for an SMS with a particular substring, and then responding with an SMS of its own (sent programmatically, without user intervention). Does anybody know how to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate as [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/990217/android-app-with-service-only)

Comment: @yorkw: Not necessarily. The requirement is for periodic processing of some event or other (in this case an incoming SMS). There's no need to run a service permanently as in the OP's question in that link. Using a `BroadcastReceiver` and `IntentService` would do the job.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To expand on Darth Beleg's answer. It's not actually possible to do what you're describing (at least not exactly).

The only way you can detect an incoming SMS, as Darth explains, is to listen for an `Intent`. The reason why it's not possible to do exactly what you want is that it's not possible for a `Service` to listen for an `Intent`.

I'd recommend a `BroadcastReceiver` which listens for the `Intent` and then starts an `IntentService` (rather than a `Service`) and respond accordingly. `IntentServices` don't run all of the time - they're started, do their work then shutdown. A much more efficient way of doing what you're looking for.

Answer (score 5):

You don't need an always-running service for this task - just set up a BroadcastReceiver listening for intents with action "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED". See [this article](http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/sms-messaging-android) for an example.