# Can we run service without creating activity ? if yes why ? or if not then why not?

Tags: android

1.i just wanted to know can i start the the service without creating activity in android. if yes why ? or if not then why not?

1. can i put my service creation code in oncreate method directaly?
2. Difference between Polymorphism and interface in java?

Comment: Have you tried it? This sounds like some homework questions. :P

Comment: Yes alextsc i m just new to android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ofcourse you can start a service without activity (like something in a receiver class)

eg

```
    public class MyStartServiceReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.d("", "in start service");
    Intent service = new Intent(context, rs.class);
    context.startService(service);
}
  }
```

and an interface is a class that is not fully defined ie: there wont be any concrete methods in it something like abstract class but an abstract class can contain concrete methods where as an interface cannot

Comment: just Google a little bit if you still have doubts ask specifically pls dont ask this broadly

Comment: Can run sample app with broadcast receiver without creating activity

Comment: i am not sure but i feel yes you can such as starting your service on a share intent after once installing but not so sure never tried

Comment: sorry you cant refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/990217/android-app-with-service-only

Answer (score 0):

1. You can do it like in the answer of "droidhot". You can call it wherever you want (p.e. onReceive, onCreate, onResume). If you want to use the same code multiple times, i would make an own method and call it in the onResume or onCreate method like this:

   ```
   @Override
   public void onResume(){
       callService();
   }

   public void callService(){
       Intent service = new Intent(getBaseContext(), myServiceClass.class);
       getBaseContext().startService(service);
   }
   ```

   Or do you mean to make service without even a class?

2.
   For the Difference between Polymorphism and interface in java I can recommend "http://java.sys-con.com/node/37695".

Comment: Can i run sample app with broadcast receiver without creating activity ?

Comment: @bkshukla why do you want to run without an activity can you specify there are methods but cant be dependend on have you reffered http://stackoverflow.com/questions/990217/android-app-with-service-only yet? it states a method of course for a sample app it ll do