# Can We Build Android App That Contain Just A Service?

Tags: android, service

Can we build android application that contains just a single service and run in background ?
and there is no application icon also ?

Comment: did you see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/990217/android-app-with-service-only

Answer (score 0):

Not really. You are welcome to write one, but nothing will ever run the service.

Comment: I seem to remember that I wrote an apk that contained just a service which exposed an AIDL interface. Another apk, running as a conventional app, made calls to functionality in the service. Admittedly the code in the service only ran when explicitly invoked.

Comment: @NickT: That's pretty much what I meant. The service will not magically run itself. Something has to use the service. It's certainly possible that this "something" is another app, with the service serving in the role of a plugin.