# andEngine Unable to instantiate service java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

Tags: android, andengine, classnotfoundexception, live-wallpaper

I've been getting my feet wet with andengine for creating a live wallpaper, overall I'm rather new with Android. 
I've been comparing different examples (it's difficult to find anything useful) and all I am trying to do is create a live wallpaper that boots, but displays a black screen.

The error I am getting is pretty common I assume

```
06-15 16:30:01.946: E/AndroidRuntime(32471): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-15 16:30:01.946: E/AndroidRuntime(32471): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate service com.example.adtime.LiveWallpaperService: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.adtime.LiveWallpaperService in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.example.adtime-2.apk]
06-15 16:30:01.946: E/AndroidRuntime(32471):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2943)
06-15 16:30:01.946: E/AndroidRuntime(32471):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$3300(ActivityThread.java:125)
06-15 16:30:01.946: E/AndroidRuntime(32471):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2087)
06-15 16:30:01.946: E/AndroidRuntime(32471):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-15 16:30:01.946: E/AndroidRuntime(32471):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
```

Also, here is my manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.adtime"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
    <uses-feature 
        android:required="true"
        android:name="android.software.live_wallpaper">
        </uses-feature>

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <!--  Live Wallpaper Service -->
        <service android:name="com.example.adtime.LiveWallpaperService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_WALLPAPER" 
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" 
            android:description="@string/wallpaper_description">
        <intent-filter android:priority="1">
            <action android:name="android.service.wallpaper.WallpaperService"/>
        </intent-filter> 
        <meta-data android:name="android.service.wallpaper"
            android:resource="@xml/wallpaper"/>
        </service>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Based on what I have been reading the problem seems to lie in the manifest somewhere I am just unsure where. I've been looking at different exampled and I feel I've made it correctly but obviously not.
The apk installs but as soon as I open the live wallpaper I get the errors there. (I am trying on an actual device)

Also, I do have the libraries set up and linked but I do not have a libs folder with jar's as I believe that is the old way.

Any information you can give will be most helpful, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This error is probably happening because your app contains only a service. As stated in this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16788828/can-we-build-android-app-that-contain-just-a-service), you cannot create an app with a service only.

Comment: Hmm, what exactly is missing then? I have LiveWallpaperService.java which should be running when the wallpaper starts and it is supposed to create the "camera" and then set the background color. From my knowledge this should be sufficient for establishing a base to start working from but if I am missing something what would I have to do?

Comment: A service is a component that runs in the background, e.g., it does not have any UI. You need at least one [activity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) for your app to run (and, incidentally, to actually have a UI).

Comment: My package was improperly named, I changed it and it worked just fine.

Answer (score 0):

The WallpaperService only can be tested on devices, don't use Android emulator. You don't need `android:required="true`.

You need to add an activity in the android manifest:

```
<activity android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:name=".Settings"
            android:exported="true"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.WallpaperSettings"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
```

Comment: I left a comment on another answer, you are right, but in this instance my issue was an improperly named package.