# How to install service without using any activity?

Tags: android, service, android-activity, installation, uninstallation

I am developing a android app that contains only service , no activity. I want that if i install that app in the device it should be installed as a service , with a condition that it should not appear in the main menu or in the manage apps. Or is it possible to make a app that can not be uninstalled.

Thanks

Comment: do u want to write a virus? you cannot write an application which cannot be uninstalled by user , and also your service should start at least once by user.

Comment: no not a virus, just want to write a service that runs in backgroud.

Comment: It will appear in manage apps. I don't think you can change that. Apps that are device administrators can disable uninstalling of themselves (my antivirus does this) but the administrator status can be removed by the user.

Comment: It's possible to create a service only app, which won't be shown on launcher. However, it will still be displayed in manage apps since users have a right to uninstall any app that they don't need. (with exception to system apps)

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/990217/android-app-with-service-only