# How to make an Android app only run background services, and not be launcheable?

Tags: android, android-studio, launcher, android-launcher

Is it possible to create an app without any activities? Without a launcher icon and without the "open" button on Play Store? Like this one https://my.pcloud.com/publink/show?code=XZUi3I7Z6yNkHyuBISL5XynlYYI8SjEJcoMk

I only need it to create a background service.
I've done some research and I haven't found anything about this. If you could just point me in a direction (or tell me it's not possible) it would be great!
Cheers!

Comment: I don't think your app can be notified after install to start a service and I don't think you can start any services until your app has been opened by the user.

Comment: [Or maybe I'm wrong...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/990217/how-to-start-service-only-android-app)

Comment: My intent was to create a quick settings button. That would then toggle said service. And I know an app can create a quick settings button without being opened. And quick settings buttons are services in themselves so yeah... I think it's possible. I am sure a quick settings can be created without running the app. I've downloaded am app that does this. But it still has an activity as a place holder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said you didn't want to use a translucent Activity, but that seems to be the best way to do this:

1- In your Manifest, set the Activity theme to `Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.`

2- Don't bother with a layout for your Activity, and don't call `setContentView().`

3- In your Activity's `onCreate()`, start your Service with `startService()`.

4- Exit the Activity with `finish()` once you've started the Service.

In other words, your Activity doesn't have to be visible; it can simply make sure your Service is running and then exit, which sounds like what you want.

how to hide luncher icon :

```
PackageManager p = getPackageManager();
ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(this, com.apps.MainActivity.class); // activity which is first time open in manifiest file which is declare as <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
p.setComponentEnabledSetting(componentName,PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
```

Hide open button couldn't be done , because we are talking about an application and not a google library

how to unhide icon :

```
PackageManager p = getPackageManager();
ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(this, com.apps.MainActivity.class);
p.setComponentEnabledSetting(componentName, PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
```

IMPORTANT: It's somehow tricky if you need to do something with main activity in your app when it's hidden. you will face an `ActivityNotFoundException`. to make it work, you should unhide icon before doing anything to your main activity and hide it again after you are finished.

Comment: How would I then start the service without a luncher to start the app?

Comment: you should hide it after the first lunch , other wise it's not possible , check my edit

Comment: Ok I'll try it out and come back to you c: Ty!